# Basis of the CGI model of SS Botany Bay in ST:TOS "Space Seed" re-release

Tags: props, effects, star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series

In the original release of the Star Trek TOS episode "Space Seed", shots depicting the exterior of the Botany Bay only ever show it in profile, never revealing the true shape of the physical model. In the re-release, we get to see it from other angles. What was the basis of the CGI model? Was it faithful to the original physical model (do we even know)? Did the original physical model still exist to become the pattern? Was it captured from different angles in other media (other movies, production stills, etc.)?

I could extend the question to a few other ships featured on the show where you don't see them from enough angles to get a clear sense of their true shapes. I often wonder how faithful the CGI render of the Romulan "bird of prey" in TOS "Balance of Terror" re-release is to the original effects model.

The two big exceptions to my question are the Enterprise and the Klingon battle cruiser. In both cases, the original release effects shots covered them from enough angles, and both had model kits and other reasonably reliable sources (plans, etc.) issued during the show's original run.

Comment: __[Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/DY-100_class#Studio_models)__ has a section on that, plus [this picture](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/3/35/DY-100_and_USS_Enterprise_studio_models_filmed_at_Film_Effects_of_Hollywood.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110413134831&path-prefix=en) of the original model being filmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CGI model matches the form of the studio used Botany Bay, a DY-100 class ship. One of the original studio models is housed at the Smithsonian museum.

[image]

And it matches the original sketch designs of the DY-100 ships.

Aside from a few retcons like the Woden, all the cgi models are very true to form of the originals. Any significant difference would be highly criticized by nerd and normals alike. Except for the gaudiness that the cgi models add. The original props look so much better.